# Splitting a SQLAlchemy hybrid field return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model running against a Postgresql database. In my model I have an `invoice_number` string field, which sorts like this:

- 2022-01-1
- 2022-01-10
- ...
- 2022-01-2
- ...

(I would like them to sort `-1, -2, ..., -10, ...`)

In order to sort this I would like to have a hybrid field that returns (and properly sorts) the string as tuple, split by the `-`.

In my model I so far have (the code uses Flask-SQLalchemy, which wraps SQLalchemy stuff behind the `db` object, otherwise the same):

```
class Orders(db.Model):
    invoice_number = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def invoice_number_parts(self):
        return self.invoice_number.split("-")

    @invoice_number_parts.expression
    def invoice_number_parts(cls):
        from sqlalchemy import func
        return func.split(cls.invoice_number)
```

This gives me a `ValueError: Invalid model property name <class 'webshop.models.Orders'>.invoice_number_parts`

The [tutorial mentions Functions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#working-with-sql-functions) but I cannot find the documentation for what predefined functions are available for Postgresql (I presume this would be possible with the `string_to_array` [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)).

Am I completely off here in my approach? I do not need a setter for this, and I understand the `hybrid_property` as returning the value, the `@...expression` as the SQL-generating part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant Postgresql function is [split_parts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html), which takes a string value (the column), a delimiter ('-') and a 1-based index as its arguments (the index can be negative in Postgresql 14).

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

class Orders(Base):
    ...

    @hybrid_property
    def invoice_number_parts(self):
        return self.invoice_number.split("-")

    @invoice_number_parts.expression
    def invoice_number_parts(cls):
        # Split by '-', get the third column and cast to an integer.
        return sa.cast(sa.func.split_part(cls.invoice_number, '-', 3), sa.Integer)
```