# OperationalError('(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: split_part')

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to access and filter out match results by checking for str values eg `'30:20'` in the `allocations.room_number` column from `allocations` table. I am using `flask-sqlalchemy` and would like to filter out all matching results by using the `split_part()` from the `sqlalchemy func` module. I am splitting on the `allocations.room_number` because it has the value separated by `:`

```
check_already_added = db.session.query(allocations).filter(and_(allocations.name == "Filiday", func.split_part(allocations.room_number,':',0) == 30 )).first()
if check_already_added is None:
    print(check_already_added)
```

I get the below error

```
OperationalError('(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: split_part')
```

I tried using [Splitting a SQLAlchemy hybrid field return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70593557/splitting-a-sqlalchemy-hybrid-field-return-value)
but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?
I appreciate your help

Comment: where does `split_part` come from ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ... ``` using the split_part() from the sqlalchemy func module. ```
As I explained  sqlalchemy func module. I also followed the example link I shared below my question.
Thank you.
Kindly help